# Attempting to Migrate TFS2012 project from one server to another using TFS Integration Platform

Tags: tfsintegrationplatform

I have migrated all of the Version Control items with no issue. The Work Items are a different story. I always end up with a SoapException: SourceAreaId. Both projects use the same Process Template. I've used IntegrationPlatformMappingTool.exe to create the FieldMappings. I know there is one other person who has experienced this issue, but there was no resolution. They reported the issue on [CodePlex](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/workitem/24270) and [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/68d078cd-d12a-42be-b515-96d121df372f/systemwebservicesprotocolssoapexception-sourceareaid?forum=tfsintegration)

I'm not really sure what else to try. Any thoughts?

```
[6/26/2014 10:38:27 AM] TfsMigrationShell.exe Information: 0 : WorkItemTracking: Unresolved conflict:  
[6/26/2014 10:38:27 AM]   Session Group: 36bc61df-f2f8-4be0-9f9e-16f3c4c0e488 
[6/26/2014 10:38:27 AM]   Message: Cannot find applicable resolution rule. 
[6/26/2014 10:38:27 AM]   Conflict Type: TFS WIT general conflict type 
[6/26/2014 10:38:27 AM]   Conflict Type Reference Name: 470f9617-fc96-4166-96eb-44cc2cf73a97 
[6/26/2014 10:38:27 AM]   Conflict Details: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: SourceAreaId 
[6/26/2014 10:38:27 AM]    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.HandleReply(TfsClientOperation operation, TfsMessage message, Object[]& outputs) 
[6/26/2014 10:38:27 AM]    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.Invoke(TfsClientOperation operation, Object[] parameters, TimeSpan timeout, Object[]& outputs) 
[6/26/2014 10:38:27 AM]    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.Invoke(TfsClientOperation operation, Object[] parameters, Object[]& outputs) 
[6/26/2014 10:38:27 AM]    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.Invoke(TfsClientOperation operation, Object[] parameters) 
[6/26/2014 10:38:27 AM]    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.ClientService3.GetWorkItemLinkChanges(Int64 rowVersion) 
[6/26/2014 10:38:27 AM]    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.WorkItemServer.GetWorkItemLinkChanges(String requestId, Int64 rowVersion) 
[6/26/2014 10:38:27 AM]    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Migration.Tfs2010WitAdapter.Tfs2010WorkItemServer.GetWorkItemLinkChanges(String requestId, Int64 rowVersion) 
[6/26/2014 10:38:27 AM]    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Migration.Tfs2010WitAdapter.TfsMigrationWorkItemStore.GetLinkChanges(Int64& linkChangeIdHighWaterMark, DateTime excludeItemsChangedBeforeTime) 
[6/26/2014 10:38:27 AM]    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Migration.Tfs2010WitAdapter.TfsMigrationWorkItemStore.GetItemsWithLinkChanges(Int64& linkChangeIdHighWaterMark, DateTime excludeItemsChangedBeforeTime) 
[6/26/2014 10:38:27 AM]    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Migration.Tfs2010WitAdapter.Linking.Tfs2010LinkProvider.GenerateNextLinkDeltaSlice(LinkService linkService, Int32 maxDeltaSliceSize)
```

Comment: Anything in your server logs? Tried turning on TFS Client traces? See: http://larzjoakimnilzzon.blogspot.nl/2012/04/tracelogging-configuration-in-team.html More details will help, not many folks seem to have run into this, meaning it's probably impossible for us to recreate the situation you're in.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I've added the Client Traces and will re-attempt the migration shortly and see what we get in the logs.

Comment: Using Fiddler2, I was able to gather more information. It appears the tool is calling the "GetWorkItemLinkChanges" method. The method expects a Request ID and Row Version (string, long). All that is provided is the Request ID (no row version). The error returned from the web service is: IndexOutOfRangeException: SourceAreaId. I'll download the source and see if I can step through it. Maybe there is some data issue on the other TFS server? If any of this "rings a bell" for anyone, let me know. Thanks again!

Comment: After opening up the tools code and tracing the line of code where it gets the work item link changes, I decided the work item link changes are not important for our needs. I couldn't find any documentation that explained how to create a rule to "skip" or "ignore" a general conflict type, so I updated the code to simply ignore if the exception "IndexOutOfRangeException: SourceAreaId" occurs on that method.